# Как правильно прописать в кадровом приказе?

Tags: грамотная-речь, род

«... в лице начальника учреждения, Ивановой Татьяны Ивановны, действующей / действующего...»

Answer (score 2):

(1) На мой взгляд нет причин обособлять ФИО начальника (здесь ФИО так же значимы, как и должность). Вот что пишет об этом Розенталь:

> [§93. Обособленные приложения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)
>   4.Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если служит для пояснения или уточнения нарицательного существительного (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова «а зовут его», «а именно», «то есть», см. §97), например: Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Тургенев); У дверей, на солнышке, зажмурившись, лежала любимая борзая собака отца – Милка (Л.Толстой); А братья Ани, Петя и Андрюша, гимназисты, дергали его [отца] сзади за фрак и шептали сконфуженно... (Чехов).

В этом случае действует правило:

> в) определение-причастие ставится в форме женского рода независимо от порядка слов: Предложившая новую статью автор Н. Петрова уже известна читателям. Автор Н. Петрова, предложившая новую статью, уже известна читателям. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89)

**...в лице начальника учреждения Ивановой Татьяны Ивановны, действующей...**

(2) Если же Вы считаете ФИО уточняющей информацией, то следует их обособить. Тогда причастный оборот будет относиться к слову *начальника* и должен будет стоять в мужском роде:

**...в лице начальника учреждения, Ивановой Татьяны Ивановны, действующего...**

Comment: большое спасибо за разъяснение